# How do I prove $ A ∪ B = ( A ∩ B ) ∪ ( A ∖ B ) ∪ ( B ∖ A ) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

It makes intuitive sense to me but the proving just doesn't seem satisfactory.
One way that the author uses in the examples is something along the lines :

Let $x \in (A \space \cap B) \cup (A - B) \cup (B - A)$

$\implies (x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \in A)$

Now it is pretty obvious to me that

$\implies(x \in A \lor x \in B)$

$\implies x \in (A \cup B)$

But how do I account for the fact that all these "intermediate" operations just seem to happen. How do I "justify" this jump?

P.S. : I'm just starting to learn abstract algebra via [AATA](http://abstract.ups.edu/) and just feel that I should be able to justify every statement but how do I go about it just doesn't strike me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should read $(x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin A)$

From $(x \in A \land x \in B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin A)$ we get three cases:

1. $x \in A \land x \in B$, then $x \in A \cap B$, hence $x\in A\cup B$.
2. $x \in A \land x \notin B$, then $x \in A$, hence $x \in A \cup B.$
3. $x \in B \land x \notin A$, then $x \in B$, hence $x \in A \cup B.$

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But all of these cases do seem to amount to $x \in A \lor x \in B \implies x \in (A \cup B)$.

Comment: Are you wanting justification for $x\in A\lor x\in B \Longrightarrow x\in A\cup B$?

Comment: No, I belive that is autojustified by the definition of union. I apologise, it seems I have not worded my doubts clearly. Thanks.